# How can I use ForeignKey to provide field choices for two separate fields within the same model and pointing to the same model?

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

From the model form CustomerCatalog I want to fill in data referenced from my ProductCatalog model.  I know I could set up a separate model/table for one of them but that just means I have to update data in two separate locations.

```
class CustomerCatalog(models.Model):
"""
"""

id = models.AutoField
account = models.ForeignKey('Account', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Account to which this product was sold.')
ccname = models.ForeignKey('ProductCatalog', to_field='name', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name="Product name")
ccproductid = models.ForeignKey('ProductCatalog', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Product ID", related_name='ccpid+')
unit = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Unit of measurement.', null=True, blank=True, default='VM')
unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, help_text="Enter price per unit.", null=True, blank=True)
total_qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, help_text="Enter quantity.", null=True, blank=True)
total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, help_text="Enter total price (note this will be calculated in a future release).", null=True, blank=True)
history = HistoricalRecords()

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Customer Catalog'

def __str__(self):
    """
    String for representing the Model object (in Admin site etc.)
    """
    return f'{self.ccname}'


class ProductCatalog(models.Model):
    """
    """

    #UNIT_CHOICES = ('Ea', 'Account', 'VM', 'Hr', 'Project', 'Mbps', 'Rack unit', 'Appliance', 'micro-VM', 'GB')

    servicecat = models.ForeignKey('Service', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Enter the service in which this product belongs.')
    id = models.CharField(max_length=40, help_text="Enter Product ID.", primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Enter name of resource unit that will be used with service definitions.", unique=True)
    billing = models.CharField(max_length=70, help_text="Enter billing type.")
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=80, help_text='Unit of measurement.')
    short_description = models.TextField(max_length=400, help_text="Enter the description of the service.", blank=True)
    version = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, help_text="Enter date of the CPS version.")
    org = models.ForeignKey(OrgUnit, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text="Enter organization providing the service.")
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Product Catalog'

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object (in Admin site etc.)
        """
        return f'{self.name}'
```

EDIT:
I decided to go a little different route on this based on the answer given by Josewails.  I decided calculating one of the fields was a much better option than what I was trying to do and the way he described calling the data informed me of how I should do it.  Thank you.  Here's my final code:

```
class CustomerCatalog(models.Model):
    """
    Model for representing products that have been sold and are being used by a specific customer.
    """

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ccproductid = models.ForeignKey('ProductCatalog', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name="Product ID")
    ccname = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Product name", blank=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey('Account', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Account to which this product was sold.')
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Unit of measurement.', null=True, blank=True, default='VM')
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, help_text="Enter price per unit.", null=True, blank=True)
    total_qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, help_text="Enter quantity.", null=True, blank=True)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, help_text="Enter total price (note this will be calculated in a future release).", null=True, blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    @property
    def get_ccname(self):
        return self.ccproductid.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ccname = self.get_ccname
        super(CustomerCatalog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Customer Catalog'

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object (in Admin site etc.)
        """
        return f'{self.ccproductid}'


class ProductCatalog(models.Model):
    """
    Model to represent the full product portfolio.
    """


    id = models.CharField(max_length=40, help_text="Enter Product ID.", primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Enter name of resource unit that will be used with service definitions.", unique=True)
    billing = models.CharField(max_length=70, help_text="Enter billing type.")
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=80, help_text='Unit of measurement.')
    short_description = models.TextField(max_length=400, help_text="Enter the description of the service.", blank=True)
    version = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, help_text="Enter date of the CPS version.")
    servicecat = models.ForeignKey('Service', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Enter the service in which this product belongs.')
    org = models.ForeignKey(OrgUnit, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text="Enter organization providing the service.")
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Product Catalog'

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object (in Admin site etc.)
        """
        return f'{self.id}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have a field 'product' which is a `ForeignKey` and have methods to get the name and id

This would be something like this,

```
class ProductCatalog(models.Model):

    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, help_text="Enter Product ID.", primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                            help_text="Enter name of resource unit that will be used with service definitions.",
                            unique=True)


class CustomerCatalog(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductCatalog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def product_id(self):
        return self.product.product_id

    def product_name(self):
        return self.product.name
```

**Note**: You can't have a field named `id` because it will conflict with Django's own autogenerated `id` field.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I have a question though.  When you define those methods, do those also create fields in the model?  I will need fields to contain both the product ID and product name in the customer catalog.  I just tried it and got an error but it may be related to my make files getting out of whack again.  i'm about to recreate my DB from scratch.

Comment: No, these are not fields.  Only the product will be stored in your DB. So, What happens is; if for instance, you call `customer.product_name` it accesses the product associated with the customer and returns its name field.  Also, I made a small edit of the `product_id` method.